# Contenteditable safari mobile, when setting focus the page layout jumps

Tags: ios, angularjs, angular-material

Actual Behavior:

What is the issue? * When clicking on a contenteditable, the page jumps down.
What is the expected behavior? It should behave just as input fields, where the page scrolls to that element.
CodePen (or steps to reproduce the issue): *

CodePen Demo which shows your issue: http://codepen.io/pennybirman/pen/KaErKb

```
<body layout="column" ng-app="myApp" ng-cloak>
  <md-content>
    <div contenteditable="true" class="editables">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis, magni omnis ad nihil voluptate harum fuga aut voluptatum incidunt ut libero ex, itaque eligendi repellendus, impedit. Possimus blanditiis ex nam.</div>
    <div contenteditable="true" class="editables">Illum libero, praesentium quibusdam vitae, nam voluptatum earum doloribus deleniti magnam consequatur cum dolorem, eos? Blanditiis harum molestias recusandae officiis esse! Quia doloribus accusantium, recusandae illum debitis sunt laborum assumenda!</div>
    <div contenteditable="true" class="editables">Illum libero, praesentium quibusdam vitae, nam voluptatum earum doloribus deleniti magnam consequatur cum dolorem, eos? Blanditiis harum molestias recusandae officiis esse! Quia doloribus accusantium, recusandae illum debitis sunt laborum assumenda!</div>
    <div contenteditable="true" class="editables">Illum libero, praesentium quibusdam vitae, nam voluptatum earum doloribus deleniti magnam consequatur cum dolorem, eos? Blanditiis harum molestias recusandae officiis esse! Quia doloribus accusantium, recusandae illum debitis sunt laborum assumenda!</div>
    <div contenteditable="true" class="editables">Illum libero, praesentium quibusdam vitae, nam voluptatum earum doloribus deleniti magnam consequatur cum dolorem, eos? Blanditiis harum molestias recusandae officiis esse! Quia doloribus accusantium, recusandae illum debitis sunt laborum assumenda!</div>
    <div contenteditable="true" class="editables">Illum libero, praesentium quibusdam vitae, nam voluptatum earum doloribus deleniti magnam consequatur cum dolorem, eos? Blanditiis harum molestias recusandae officiis esse! Quia doloribus accusantium, recusandae illum debitis sunt laborum assumenda!</div>
    <div contenteditable="true" class="editables">Illum libero, praesentium quibusdam vitae, nam voluptatum earum doloribus deleniti magnam consequatur cum dolorem, eos? Blanditiis harum molestias recusandae officiis esse! Quia doloribus accusantium, recusandae illum debitis sunt laborum assumenda!</div>
  </md-content>
</body>
```

Details: Has to be tested in a iOS mobile device. (Verified it in browserStack, and xCode with ios10).
Angular Versions: *

Angular Version: 1.5.7
Angular Material Version:1.1.0
Additional Information:

Browser Type: * Safari mobile.

Browser Version: *10.0

OS: *iOS 10.

Stack Traces: No errors, just UI behaviour.

Video:: https://youtu.be/6U6BtxQggJ8

Comment: Has anyone had a similar problem? Any quick fix?

Answer (score 0):

Justin (Support Engineer from Ionic Team) said that it is not recommended to use contenteditable divs. 
Source: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/4162 (check latest comment)

Comment: You need to include the parts of the link that is necessary to help the asker understand what you mean